# Git Tag not available on some branches

Tags: git, github, git-describe

While merging my stage branch to master branch for production release, I created and pushed a tag on stage branch using the following commands:

```
git tag base-2.0.0
git push origin --tags
```

Now, when I check the distance of the current commit from this tag, using the following command, it gives me correct result for stage and master branches.

```
git describe --tags --match base-2.0.0
```

However, for other branches like qa and develop, the above command shows the following result:

```
fatal: No tags can describe '<commit id>'.
```

I have already merged stage and master branches down to qa and develop branches. Can someone please suggest what is the issue and how to fix that? Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe if you rebased your qa/develop on top of master then it should work.

Comment: You could show us how your history looks like, with `git log -a --oneline --graph --decorate`. I suspect like @C1sc0 that your branches qa and develop don't have the tagged commit as child.

Comment: @Gauthier Please check the git history of the repo at https://drive.google.com/file/d/19EgN7aPHeEhvjTE0qBE7m7pok-0v67UO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SandeepParashar sorry, no, not looking at a repo in google drive :) Publish the repo at github or similar, instead.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. The Google Drive link points to a text file containing the output of the command "git log -a --oneline --graph --decorate"
I am afraid that I can't share the GitHub repo access directly as the repo belongs to the client. However, things seem to work now after rebasing. 
Thanks a lot to you and @C1sc0